# Retorno de função assíncrona

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando retornar o valor de uma query usando Sequelize mas sempre vem como Undefined. Imagino que seja devido a ser uma função assíncrona.

```js
const { Sequelize, sequelize } = require('../../config/database');

// Classe para realizar manipulação dos usuarios no banco
class UserDAO{
    // Consultar registros no banco pelas credenciais passadas pelo controller
    userQuery(userCredentials){   
        sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='${userCredentials.user}' AND senha='${userCredentials.pass}'`).then((result) => {
            return result;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);            
        });
    }

}

module.exports = UserDAO;
```

A classe UserDAO é instanciada em um outro arquivo e a função userQuery() é chamada passando um objeto como argumento. Eu preciso que a função userQuery() retorne o valor do then() da sequelize.query().

Comment: tente dar um console.log(result) e coloca aqui o que aparece no seu log

Comment: Dentro da função sequelize.query() ele mostra o objeto que é retornado pela query (como deveria acontecer). Ou seja, tudo funciona perfeitamente bem dentro da função, entretanto quando eu tento externar isso de alguma maneira ele fica undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vou tentar te ajudar tenta fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
const { Sequelize, sequelize } = require('../../config/database');

// Classe para realizar manipulação dos usuarios no banco
function pesquisa() {
class UserDAO{
    // Consultar registros no banco pelas credenciais passadas pelo controller
    userQuery(userCredentials){   
        sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='${userCredentials.user}' AND senha='${userCredentials.pass}'`).then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
            return result;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);            
        });
    }

  }
}

pesquisa()
```

provavelmente isso resolva, fique de olho pra ver o resultado do log, se tudo der certo exporte essa função como um objeto **JSON** dessa maneira:

```
    const { Sequelize, sequelize } = require('../../config/database');

    // Classe para realizar manipulação dos usuarios no banco
module.exports = {
pesquisa: function(){
class UserDAO{
        // Consultar registros no banco pelas credenciais passadas pelo controller
        userQuery(userCredentials){   
            sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login='${userCredentials.user}' AND senha='${userCredentials.pass}'`).then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
                return result;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);            
            });
        }

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu td certo!

Comment: que bom que pude contribuir de alguma forma, não esquece de marcar a resposta como correta.